# Query Firebase Database Swift

Tags: json, swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to create some queries for my database but without success. This is the first time when dealing with queries in Firebase and find them a bit confusing.

I use a real-time database

My database looks like this :

```
-> users
    ->profile
        ->uid1
            ->email : "some@email.com"
            ->name : "some_name"
            ->favourite
               ->id1
                   ->title : "some_title"
                   ->date : "some_date"
                   ->id : "id1"
               ->id2
                   ->title : "some_title"
                   ->date : "some_date"
                   ->id : "id2"
        ->uid2
            ->email : "some@email.com"
            ->name : "some_name"
            ->favourite
               ->id1
                   ->title : "some_title"
                   ->date : "some_date"
                   ->id : "id1"
               ->id2
                   ->title : "some_title"
                   ->date : "some_date"
                   ->id : "id2"
```

The queries I've been trying to make:

- Check whether a specific uid is already in the database.
- Check whether a specific id from favourite is already in the database at a known uid.

Any ideas how to perform these queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends if you are using the real-time database or Firestore. But because you want to do queries I suggest to use Firestore and you could implement it this way:

```
 // Create a path where you want the query to search
 let storageReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("users/profile")

 let query = storageReference.whereField("uid", isEqualTo: givenUID )
        query.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let snapshot = snapshot {
                for document in snapshot.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                }
            }
        }
```

In real-time database you can't use queries but you can implement it like this and see if the document is available:

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users/profile/givenUID")

databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.exists() {
            // UID is in the database
        } else {
            // UID not found
        }
})
```

Then do the same with a reference for favorites!

Comment: I use a real time database

Comment: I updated the answer! please check the answer as valid if this works for you :)